# compare two list of dicts in python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I want to compare two lists of dictionaries in python, I have a list sent from the frontend and a query result stored in the same function, so all I want is to compare both of the lists with the key `barcode` and if they matches I want to append the `name` from the second dictionary to the first one

for example:

```
data_from_frontend = [
    { barcode: '1', name_en: 'milk' },
    { barcode: '2', name_en: 'water' },
    { barcode: '3', name_en: 'cheese' },
    { barcode: '10', name_en: 'pepsi' },
]
result_from_query = [
    { barcode: '1', name: 'PID012343' },
    { barcode: '2', name: 'PID123454' },
    { barcode: '10', name: 'PID123432' },
]
```

I want to compare both of the lists and by the `barcode` and if they match I want to merge the the pair of both variables to a new one + adding the one the doesn't match to another list, so the outcome would be two new variables with the `[matched + name]` and `not_found`, how can I achieve that ?

Here is what i've tried

```
equal = []
not_equal = []
no_barcode = []
x = [ { "age": "22" }, { "name": "John Doe" }, { "name": "Jane Doe" }, { "name": "Doctor" }, { "name": "Engineer" } ]
y = [ { "name": "Engineer" }, { "name": "Jane Doe" }, { "name": "Doctor" } ]
x_sort = sorted(x, key=lambda k: ("name" not in k, k.get("name", None)))
y_sort = sorted(y, key=lambda k: ("name" not in k, k.get("name", None)))
print(y_sort)
for x_val in x_sort:
    if "name" not in x_val.keys():
        no_barcode.append(x_val)
    else:
        for y_val in y_sort:
            if x_val["name"] == y_val["name"]:
                equal.append(x_val)
                mapped = map(lambda k: k["name"], y_sort)
                if x_val["name"] not in mapped:
                    not_equal.append(x_val)
print('equal')
print(equal)
print('not equal')
print(not_equal)
```

Comment: can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: can you provide the expected output in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should fix your dict keys and enclose them into quotes.

Then you can use [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to find items, for example:

```
print('initial dict:')
pprint.pprint(data_from_frontend)

for item in result_from_query:
    item_found = next((i for i in data_from_frontend if i['barcode'] == item['barcode']), False)
    if item_found:
        item_found['name'] = item['name']

print('dict after search:')
pprint.pprint(data_from_frontend)
```

will produce:

```
initial dict:
[{'barcode': '1', 'name_en': 'milk'},
 {'barcode': '2', 'name_en': 'water'},
 {'barcode': '3', 'name_en': 'cheese'},
 {'barcode': '10', 'name_en': 'pepsi'}]
dict after search:
[{'barcode': '1', 'name': 'PID012343', 'name_en': 'milk'},
 {'barcode': '2', 'name': 'PID123454', 'name_en': 'water'},
 {'barcode': '3', 'name_en': 'cheese'},
 {'barcode': '10', 'name': 'PID123432', 'name_en': 'pepsi'}]
```

Using `False` in generator will avoid error when searching by barcode value not existing in target dict.

**P.S.** dont forget to import `pprint` if you want to use it

**P.P.S.** and sure you can create new dict instead of modifying existing one, using same logic

Comment: Great, this answer is working fine in jupyter, I'll try to implement it on the server and check,

Answer (score 0):

Your barcode matching results can be get like this.

```
barcode = 'barcode'
name_en = 'name_en'
name = 'name'

matching_result = data_from_frontend[:] #get a copy of front end data to use as the output

for i in range(len(data_from_frontend)):
    for j in range(len(result_from_query)):
        if(data_from_frontend[i][barcode] == result_from_query[j][barcode]):
            matching_result[i][name] = result_from_query[j][name]
            break

print(matching_result)
```